# Unable to post textarea jquery

Tags: jquery, json

This is what I have tried so far; and these are the values it is returning:

```
$('input[name=message]').toString()
"[object Object]"

$('input[name=message]').val()
undefined

$('input[name=message]').toString()
"[object Object]"

$('input[name=message]').html()
null
```

Can anyone suggest how I can post the text within json?

This is the current code:

```
$('form input[type=image]').click(function() {
        var $data =     'name=' + $('input[name=name]').val() + '&' +
                        'email=' + $('input[name=email]').val() + '&' +
                        'country=' + $('input[name=country]').val() + '&' +
                        'contact=' + $('input[name=contact]').val() + '&' +
                        'message=' + $('input[name=message]').val() + '&' +
                        'service=' + $('input[name=service]:selected').val() + '&' +
                        'csrf=' + $('input[name=csrf]').val();

        $.post( 'http://www.site.com/system/sendemail.php',
                $data,
                function($data, $textStatus) {
                    if ($data.success) {
                        $('input[name=name]').val();
                        $('input[name=email]').val();
                        $('input[name=country]').val();
                        $('input[name=contact]').val();
                        $('input[name=message]').val();
                        $('input[name=service]').attr('selected', '');
                        $('input[name=csrf]').val($data.newCSRF);
                    }
                    $.prompt($data.result);

                },
                'json');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Why can't you use just `$('#inputid').val()`?

Comment: please show your form

Comment: Submitting a form like this can go bad quickly as the form grows, take a look at jquery [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is textarea , use `textarea` instead of `input`.

Instead of:

```
$('input[name=message]').val()
```

try this:

```
$('textarea[name=message]').val()
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use wrong selector, I think you must change input into textarea:

```
 $('textarea[name=message]')
```

Comment: This gives me: message:[object Object] - i'll post my form